# LISP Special Forms for Conditionals

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am reading the book *Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming : Case studies in Common LISP* by Peter Norvig, and in the chapter about the special forms for conditionals it says that they all can be replaced by the if form

```
(when test a b c) == (if test (progn a b c)) 
(unless test x y) == (if (not test) (progn x y) 
(and a b c) == (if a (if b c)) 
(or a b c) == (if a a (if b b c)) 
(case a (b c) (t  x)) == (if (eql a 'b) c x)
```

I don't understant how that works, could anyone explain it to me? What about the `cond` form, can it also be replaced by the if form? Can I then create a macro-function with the `if` form to replace `when`, `unless`, `and`, etc...?

Comment: you already got an answer, but if you want more to read and/or exercises, I suggest the chapter `conditionals` in [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/).

Answer (score 8):

`IF` is a general purpose conditional that chooses from two branches depending on a single condition. All those others are just easier ways to write it when there are more than two branches (`AND`, `OR`, `CASE`) or only one branch (`WHEN`, `UNLESS`).

`COND` can also be done with `IF`, for example:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun ifify-clauses (clauses)
    (when clauses
      (destructuring-bind (condition form) (first clauses)
        `(if ,condition ,form ,(ifify-clauses (rest clauses)))))))

(defmacro if-cond (&body clauses)
  (ifify-clauses clauses))

(macroexpand '(if-cond
                ((= 3 1) "foo")
                ((= 3 2) "bar")
                ((= 3 3) "quux")))
;=> (IF (= 3 1)
;       "foo"
;       (IF (= 3 2)
;           "bar"
;           (IF (= 3 3)
;               "quux"
;               NIL)))
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not only possible but it's exactly what happens when you use `cond`:

```lisp
(macroexpand '(cond ((< v 0) (print "negative") (* -2 v))
                    ((> v 0) (print "positive") (1- (* 2 v)))
                    (t (print "zero") 0)))
; ==>
(if (< v 0) 
    (progn (print "negative") 
           (* -2 v))
    (if (> v 0)
        (progn (print "positive") 
               (1- (* 2 v)))
        (progn (print "zero")
               0)))
```

So when you use `cond` in CL it replaces it with the equivalent `if` form at the macro expansion stage. That happens usually once for each place the macro is used in a program.

Usually the core language does not support many ways to do the same so I guess everything will be transformed to `if` unless the implementation found a reason to keep it primitive.

The [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se) reflects this by the title of the forms as "[Special Operator `IF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm)" and "[Macro `COND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm#cond)".

You can define your own macros that do conditionals and you are free to choose of the already available conditionals to replace it with since the macros are expanded until there are no more left. Here is a definition of an [anaphoric if](http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap6.html):

```lisp
(defmacro aif (p a &optional c)
  `(let ((it ,p))
     (if it ,a ,c)))

(macroexpand '(aif (extremely-expensive-function x)
                   (use-value it)
                   (compute-other-result)))
; ==>
(let ((it (extremely-expensive-function x)))
  (if it
      (use-value it)
      (compute-other-result)))
```

Comment: @ScottM Arc fixed that by doing `(if p1 c1 p2 c2 a)` but yes, the other conditionals have pros that are the reason they are used in place of `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You are on page 53 of PoAIP. If you go on reading this page and the next ones, the explanation follows.